# How to execute an application in maximized mode?

Tags: delphi, winapi, createprocess

Based on my [**last question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881394/how-execute-a-external-program-beyond-screen-limits-and-without-show-in-taskbar?noredirect=1#comment70963744_41881394), I have a fully functional application that can execute an external process.

But there is a problem. When, for example, `Internet Explorer` is started, the browser window is not opened maximized.

How to make the browser window (or any other window) start in maximized mode?

Here is my code:

***Form:***

```
 type
      PEnumInfo = ^TEnumInfo;
      TEnumInfo = record ProcessID: DWORD; HWND: THandle; end;

    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        btn1: TButton;
        procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;
      myPID: DWORD = 0;

    implementation

  uses
  UTaskBarList;  

    {$R *.dfm}

    function EnumWindowsProc(Wnd: DWORD; var EI: TEnumInfo): Bool; stdcall;
        var
          PID: DWORD;
        begin
          GetWindowThreadProcessID(Wnd, @PID);
          Result := (PID <> EI.ProcessID) or (not IsWindowVisible(WND)) or (not IsWindowEnabled(WND));
          if not Result then EI.HWND := WND;
        end;

      function FindMainWindow(PID: DWORD): DWORD;
        var
          EI: TEnumInfo;
        begin
          EI.ProcessID := PID;
          EI.HWND := 0;
          EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsProc, Integer(@EI));
          Result := EI.HWND;
        end;

    procedure dgCreateProcess(const FileName: string);
    var ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
        StartInfo: TStartupInfo;
    begin
         FillMemory(@StartInfo, sizeof(StartInfo), 0);
         StartInfo.cb := sizeof(StartInfo);
        // StartInfo.dwX := Screen.DesktopRect.BottomRight.X;
        // StartInfo.dwY := Screen.DesktopRect.BottomRight.Y;
         CreateProcess(
                       PChar(FileName),
                       nil,
                       nil, Nil, False,
                       NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                       nil, nil,
                       StartInfo,
                       ProcInfo);

                       myPID := ProcInfo.dwProcessId;

         CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hProcess);
         CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hThread);
    end;

    procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      hWindow : DWORD;
      szRect  : TRect;
      posX, posY, windW, windH: Integer;
    begin

      dgCreateProcess('C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe');

      repeat

          hWindow := FindMainWindow(myPID);//FindWindow('IEFrame', nil);

          if hWindow > 0 then
          begin

            GetWindowRect(hWindow,szRect);

            windW := szRect.Width;
            windH := szRect.Height;

            posX := Screen.DesktopRect.BottomRight.X;
            posY := Screen.DesktopRect.BottomRight.Y;

            MoveWindow(hWindow, posX, posY, windW, windH,True);

            TTaskbarList.Remove(hWindow);

          end;
      until (IsWindowVisible(hWindow));

     ShowMessage('outside of loop');
    end;

    end.
```

***UTaskBarList:***

```
unit UTaskBarList;

interface

uses ComObj, ShlObj;

type
  ITaskbarList = interface
    [SID_ITaskbarList]
    function HrInit: HResult; stdcall;
    function AddTab(hwnd: Cardinal): HResult; stdcall;
    function DeleteTab(hwnd: Cardinal): HResult; stdcall;
    function ActivateTab(hwnd: Cardinal): HResult; stdcall;
    function SetActiveAlt(hwnd: Cardinal): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

  TTaskbarList = class
  private
    xTaskbarList: ITaskbarList;
  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure Activate(hwnd: THandle);
    procedure Add(hwnd: THandle);
    procedure Delete(hwnd: THandle);
    class procedure Insert(hwnd: THandle);
    class procedure Remove(hwnd: THandle);
  end;

implementation

constructor TTaskbarList.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  xTaskbarList := CreateComObject(CLSID_TaskbarList) as ITaskbarList;
  xTaskbarList.HrInit;
end;

procedure TTaskbarList.Activate(hwnd: THandle);
begin
  xTaskbarList.ActivateTab(hwnd);
end;

procedure TTaskbarList.Add(hwnd: THandle);
begin
  xTaskbarList.AddTab(hwnd);
end;

procedure TTaskbarList.Delete(hwnd: THandle);
begin
  xTaskbarList.DeleteTab(hwnd);
end;

class procedure TTaskbarList.Insert(hwnd: THandle);
begin
  with TTaskbarList.Create do
  begin
    Add(hwnd);
    Free;
  end;
end;

class procedure TTaskbarList.Remove(hwnd: THandle);
begin
  with TTaskbarList.Create do
  begin
    Delete(hwnd);
    Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Try setting `StartupInfo.dwFlags` to `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` and `StartupInfo.wShowWindow` to `SW_MAXIMIZE`

Comment: @quasoft, thank you, this works.

Comment: But in your previous question you wanted the app launched offscreen and/or hidden. So what does it matter whether or not its "maximised"? (Which means fill the entire space of one of possibly multiple screens on the computer. I.e. ***on-screen***),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to maximize a window in `Windows` is to call [`ShowWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) from Win32 API, passing the handle to the window and `SW_MAXIMIZE` as arguments, after the process has been started.

But when using [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425) to start a new process, you can instruct it to call [`ShowWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) for you, by setting the `wShowWindow` field of `TStartupInfo` to `SW_MAXIMIZE`.

The value you set in `wShowWindow` is only taken in account if you also set the `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` flag in the `dwFlags` field. The `dwFlags` bitfield determines whether certain members of the `TStartupInfo` record are used when the process creates a window.

Actually, [`ShowWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) is called automatically when a GUI process is started. By setting the `wShowWindow` field of `TStartupInfo` you are just telling it which value to use as argument for `nCmdShow` parameter on the first call to [`ShowWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx).

Add the following lines after `StartInfo.cb := sizeof(StartInfo);` in your code:

```
StartInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
StartInfo.wShowWindow := SW_MAXIMIZE;
```

All this is explained in documentation of [STARTUPINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx) structure:

> **wShowWindow**
>
> If `dwFlags` specifies `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW`, this member can be any of the values that can be specified in the `nCmdShow` parameter for the
>   ShowWindow function, except for `SW_SHOWDEFAULT`. Otherwise, this member
>   is ignored.
>
> For GUI processes, the first time `ShowWindow` is called, its `nCmdShow` parameter is ignored `wShowWindow` specifies the default value.
>   In subsequent calls to `ShowWindow`, the `wShowWindow` member is used if
>   the `nCmdShow` parameter of `ShowWindow` is set to `SW_SHOWDEFAULT`.

Unfortunately this does not work universally for all applications. You have to test it individually with every process that you intend to start with `CreateProcess`. For some applications setting `SW_MAXIMIZED` on the first call to `ShowWindow` might not be enough.